# Removing "Characters words" from a column

Tags: mysql

input

```
date       val              type

may        22                NB
jun        data NA            NB
Aug        available      mobile
Sep        37                mobile
jan        NA                card
nov        36                card
Dec        67                card
```

Now how to remove entire rows which is having character values in Val column 
i.e

```
date       val              type
may        22                NB
Sep        37                mobile
Sep        37                mobile
nov        36                card
Dec        67                card
```

Answer (score 0):

This will select only numbers using Regular Expression.

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE yourcolumn REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```

Explanation of regex

`^` - start of line(text)

`[0-9]` - only digits

`+` - One ore more digits.

`$` - end of line(text)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to test whether the value looks like a number. It appears MySQL supports regexes, though I've never used them there myself. Should be something like (untested):

```
WHERE val REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
```